# Ubuntu 23.04 black screen, no mouse, no keyboard during kernel upgrade and nvidia driver upgrade; reboot is normal

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, kernel

I got a black screen during a regular system update. Mouse and keyboard were also not available (all LEDs/sensors are off). I googled for my issue, but I only found results for black screens on reboot after a kernel upgrade. This is not my case and reboot works fine.

The update contains only a kernel and Nvidia driver update. So it must be related to these things.

- New Kernel: 6.2.0-32-generic
- New Nvidia driver: 535.104.05

During the installation process of the Nvidia driver I got a black screen, mouse and keyboard are not working. My two screens switch to standby mode, like if they get no signal. I still can hear that the processor is installing (or do) some stuff. After ca. 5 min of black screen, I restarted the computer and everything boots normal.

In addition, I figured out that I can NOT switch to another installed Nvidia driver, even I can't use the installed nouveau driver. It looks like some dependencies are missing, see screenshot.

[image]

After that, I used Synaptics to search for these libraries, and it turns out that they are installed (except the -dev packages).

Maybe some installation could not be completed? Any ideas what the issue occurs?

- Processor: AMD Ryzen™ 7 3700X × 16
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 2070 SUPER
- Mainboard: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C37
- Gnome 44.3
- Window manager X11

Comment: I have the same problem with my GeForce RTX 3060 (same Ubuntu version and Nvidia drivers). Screen goes black and I have to reboot after a few minutes, when I'm sure the update is done.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?